# Style element of list on hover in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have a structure:

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let product of searchResult?.products">
        Test
       <div>Content</div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And I would like to add some style to div inside li on mouseover on li. How can I do that? Using ViewChild? I cannot do this by CSS only. I have to get the position of li and apply appropriate offset-top on div inside.

Something like that https://codepen.io/agop/pen/VwwMGR
But in Angular

Comment: How come you can't do this with css? What is the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please take a look on this pen: https://codepen.io/agop/pen/VwwMGR   I need to do it in Angular

Answer (score 0):

No css?
You could use a `directive` that modifies the css, see:
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

and `hostListener` to do something on `mouseover` and `mouseout`
See: [Using CSS hover property in Angular directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950918/using-css-hover-property-in-angular-directive)

(Sorry I'm on mobile, might post code later if you're still stuck)!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any script for this. Just use css:

```
scss
li:hover > .divClass {
...
}

html
<li *ngFor="let product of searchResult?.products">
    Test
   <div class="divClass">Content</div>
 </li>
```

Comment: I have to apply  "top" property on div based on offset-top of parent li

Answer (score 0):

If you need some action, easy way to do it in template:

```
<li *ngFor="let product of searchResult?.products">
    Test
   <div 
    (mouseover)="addStyle($event)"
    (mouseout)="removeStyle($event)"
   >Content</div>
 </li>
```

Or you can listen with `ViewChildren` and `fromEvent` functional inside your component.